# Mimic Google bold font with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, function

I have a script which displays search results after typing something in the input field. I want to mimic Google by making the text **bold** which is similar to the value of the input.

I tried this:

```
$(input).live('keyup', function(){
    var makeBold = $('#Results').css("font-weight","bold");

    if ($(input).val() == $('#Results').html()) {   
        makeBold();
    }
});
```

The problem is that now everything is bold instead of just the matching value. How can I refer to the value and relate that to the Results?

Comment: makeBold is not a function...

Comment: Without the related HTML, no one can know for sure.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't learn how to do this on your own but there are [existing scripts](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) that will handle this for you.

Comment: @Michael Mior Thanks, Im looking in to it right now, looks promising:)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "__not__" that you shouldn't do this on your own. While it can be helpful to use existing scripts, it's also good to try buildings things yourself sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using the link provided by @Michael Mior

```
var makeBold = $(input).val();
$('#Results').highlight(makeBold);
```

The part of `.highlight` refers to the css which you can alter with bold or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to wrap the matching pieces of the results in a `<span style='font-weight:bold;'>` tag. You can use javascript `replace()` function to do this pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you are executing the "made bold" when you define `makeBold`. The result of `css()` assigned to `makeBold`, it isn't a function.

```
var makeBold = $('#Results').css("font-weight","bold");
```

If you want it a function, assign `makeBold` a anonymous one.

```
var makeBold = function() { $('#Results').css("font-weight","bold"); }
```

Comment: That's part of the problem, although there are other issues.

Answer (score 1):

There's some code you're not showing here. I'm not sure what's happening with your auto-completed results. From what's displaying here all that I know is that you have an input box and a results container in which I can only assume gets filled with results upon key-up (which isn't shown in your function).

Regardless of the Javascript you are setting the CSS properties on the entire `#Results` container. If there are other results in there they will also have a strong `font-weight`. Perhaps append span tags around the auto-completed result, and use `#Results span` as the selector.

**EDIT:** Assuming you have an Auto-complete function already printing out suggestions, what I would do in order to bold the typed part of the auto-completed result is by comparing their substrings upon keyup - and then wrapping them in a strong tag.

Comment: The results have classes. I can make them do anything. The problem is that I dont know how to relate value of input to anything else(several classes) in the results